# PHP Class loading -- Do I have to make sure my classes aren't unloaded?

Tags: php, oop, class

I have several classes which use static variables.

I assume that the classes are loaded into PHP when I include it in a php file being interpreted. Do I have to actively do anything to make sure that PHP does not 'unload' my class and I lose my static variables? Or does PHP simply never unload Classes once loaded? What if there's no file being interpreted at the current time? (I'm using php-cgi for my webserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static variable values within a class are set and retained within the context of a request only. If you want data to persist beyond the scope of the request, you have to use a session variable or write to a file or database.

Comment: Corbin's answer is more concise, but I think this explains it a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

Once loaded, they are not unloaded until the end of execution. Things do not persist over requests though.

Answer (score 0):

No, all your request scope classes and variables will be available until the request is complete (or a call to a termination method is made, like `die()` or `exit()` as Corbin noted in the over answer).
If you use session variables then they will be available during the session is active.

To access a class or function, you simply need to make sure the file is `include`d before you use it.